# Using MediaRecorder in Android to record the whole screen and fit any phone resolution

Tags: android, kotlin, mediarecorder

I'm utilizing MediaRecorder with Kotlin to capture the whole screen, it looks like the screen needs to be captured at its ratio, which makes sense. I try to calculate the ratio, and then the height of the width I aim to (1280).

I use `windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)` to get the screen resolution
then `val screenRatio : Double = (metrics.widthPixels.toDouble()  / metrics.heightPixels.toDouble())` for the ratio.

`val height : Double = 1280 / screenRatio;` to get the height.

I use `mMediaRecorder?.setVideoSize(1280 , height )` to record, yet in some phones I get black lines on the sides like in the picture

I also initialize the width and height in

`mMediaProjection?.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity", width, height, mScreenDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder?.getSurface(), null, null)`

I see the same result even by using metrics.widthPixels and metrics.heightPixels as the width and height. what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19175650/7210237

Comment: Any clue how to access Camera class using Kotlin?